# What does this pointer do with stringstream?

Tags: c++

What does this do why did he use ">> *this".

```
 Car::Car(std::string calculation) {
 std::stringstream(calculation) >> *this;
```

Comment: This is creating an `std::stringstream` objected initialized with `calculation` then it is running that on the `>>` operator for the current class. Look for something like `operator>>(std::stringstream& s, T& obj)` to see what it does.

Comment: For the specifics we can't really say, as that depends on what `this` is pointing to. Please create a [mcve] to show us. And also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: You can have a look on it [here at cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt). It depends on your `this` pointer, which version of this overloaded operator will be called

Comment: @SpentDeath Probably more like `operator>>(std::istream&, ...)`. One seldom use a specific stream for the overloading.

Comment: Sorry I updated the function please have a look

Comment: Car::Car(std::string calculation) {
 std::stringstream(calculation) >> *this;

Comment: You didn't show `Cat::operator>>(std::stringstream &s)` function.

Answer (score 3):

The term `std::stringstream(calculation)` constructs a `std::stringstream` object from `calculation`. Presumably, `calculation` is a `std::string` object.

`*this` evaluates to a reference to the current object.

The statement

```
std::stringstream(calculation) >> *this;
```

extracts the data from `calculation` and populates the current object. For that to work, the `operator>>` function has to be overloaded for the object type.

If the object type you are dealing with is `Foo`, look for a function with the following interface:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Foo& foo) { ... }
```

---

I would have used `std::istringstream` and a two liner. I think it makes the intention a bit clearer and the code a bit easier to follow.

```
std::istringstream str{calculation};
str >> *this;
```

Comment: what is the current object? calculation? Also what does the istream operator do for this function?

Comment: @Coder32, `this` is a pointer to the current object -- the object on which the member function is called. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this.